# Vue js почему не срабатывает функция, когда появляется новое значения ?

Tags: vue.js

```
computed: {
    counter: function(){
        var count = "";

        if(this.getCart()){
            for(var a in this.getCart()){
 // this.getCart()[a][3] - строка
                count = this.getCart()[a][3]
                break;
            }
        }
        return  count;

    }
}
```

Comment: По коду не особо понятна проблема. Может добавить watch?

Answer (score 0):

Вот что сказано в документации:

> Обратите внимание, что если определённая зависимость выходит за
>   область видимости экземпляра (т.е не реактивная), то вычисляемое
>   свойство не будет обновляться.

Переменная `count` объявлена внутри функции и не является реактивным зависимостью Vue. Следовательно, вычисляемое свойство обновляться не будет.

[В документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2) показан пример, когда вычисляемое свойство не будет обновляться. Также, там сказано:

> По умолчанию вычисляемые свойства работают только на чтение, но в
>   случае необходимости вы можете также указать и сеттер

Следовательно, чтобы решить данную проблему, объявите переменную `count` как реактивную, и измените код следующим образом:

```
data: {
   count: ''
},
computed: {
    counter: {      
       //геттер
       get: function () {
          return this.count
       },
       // сеттер:
       set: function (newValue) {
         //можно делать что-то с новым значением newValue
         if(this.getCart()){
           for(var a in this.getCart()){
             this.count = this.getCart()[a][3]
             break;
           }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Другой способ решения данной проблемы использовать `watch`, для этого переменную `counter` также необходимо сделать реактивной:

```
data: {
   count: 0,
   counter: 0
},
watch: {
   counter: function (newValue) {
       //можно делать что-то с новым значением newValue
       if(this.getCart()){
          for(var a in this.getCart()){
            this.count = this.getCart()[a][3]
            break;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed), [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) и [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).